# Return a value from Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I see the class Thread has 4 constructors:

```
public Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart start);
public Thread(ThreadStart start);
public Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart start, int maxStackSize);
public Thread(ThreadStart start, int maxStackSize);
```

**ParameterizedThreadStart**  and **ThreadStart** are delegate like this:

```
public delegate void ThreadStart();
public delegate void ParameterizedThreadStart(object obj);
```

What if I want to create thread start function that return int, for example?
I see that the constructor is good only if i want return void.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [*Task Parallel Library*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx) which allows you to have a return value. If you actually want a new thread to be allocated, you can use the right overload of [`Task.Factory.StartNew`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321263(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public int DoSomething() { return 42; }
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    int value = await Task.Factory.StartNew(
                        () => DoSomething(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

If you don't actually need the new thread allocation, and can use a thread-pool thread, then using [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) is simpler and better:

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    int value = await Task.Run(() => DoSomething());
}
```

**Edit:**

If for some odd reason you really want to use the `Thread` class, you can do this by closing over a variable and passing it to a delegate pass to `Thread.Start` and rely on the side-effect created once the thread starts running:

```
var x = 5;
var thread = new Thread(() => 
{
    var x = DoSomething();
});

thread.Start();
thread.Join(); // This will synchronously block the thread.
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Though I would **definitely try to avoid this** if you can use the TPL.

Comment: You should specify `TaskScheduler.Default` task scheduler, because any other task scheduler free to ignore `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` option.

Comment: @PetSerAl He would have to pass a custom `TaskScheduler` to this or any ancestor tasks in order for it to be anything other than `TaskScheduler.Default`.

Comment: As far I know, TPL does not create new threads, instead it just creates tasks to perform by ThreadPool. "Calling StartNew is functionally equivalent to creating a Task using one of its constructors and then calling Start to schedule it for execution." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321263(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StepUp No, that's not always the case, hence the [`TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.cs,33cd274e06874569,references)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
    public void StartThread()
    {
        ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.DoWork);
        Thread th = new Thread(pts);

        int i =5;
        th.Start(i);
    }

    public void DoWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I got data='{0}'", data);
    }
```

or shorter

```
        Thread th = new Thread(this.DoWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by creating the return value from the thread. Then you should take this variable by using a lambda expression. Assign to this variable a your "return" value from the worker thread and then it is necessary to wait till thread ends from the parent thread.

```
int value = 5; // a variable to store the return value
var thread = new Thread(() =>
    {
       value = 10; // Assign value to the return variable
    });
thread.Start();
thread.Join();
Console.WriteLine(value); // use your variable to show in parent thread
```